# How to create an array of Ellipse2D?

Tags: java, graphics, draw, shapes

I have a program that I've been working: it takes data from the user does some maths with it and then displays an ellipse to the screen, when new data is entered the old ellipses disappears and the new one replaces it. However I need the program to keep the old ellipse on the screen as well as the new ones so I can compare sizes. My solution to this is to have it so that when an ellipse is created it is stored in an array, and then the array of ellipse is drawn onto the screen, I also need it so that the user can clear the array and start over. However I cannot get the code to work.  Will you please help?

Below is the code that I used to create and draw the ellipse all of the variables used are just numbers.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setPaint(Color.white);
   g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(((Background.getWidth()) / 2) - (gblSemiMajaxis / 2), ((Background.getHeight()) / 2) - (gblsemiMinoraxis / 2), gblSemiMajaxis, gblsemiMinoraxis));
}
```

Comment: Elipse: a geometric shape.  Elipsis: a punctuation mark.

Comment: *"However I cannot get the code to work.  Will you please help?"*  What is your current code?  And I don't mean the code to draw, but the code to store the ellipses, and the code to clear the current ones.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: @Sam Castledine: what is the output from `java -version` in the command line

Comment: @Sam Castledine: don't forget to mark the correct answer (click the tick by it).

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Ian McLarid's answer:

```
// imports
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

...

ArrayList<Ellipse2D> ellipseList = new ArrayList<Ellipse2D>();

public void createEllipse(double gblSemiMajaxis, double gblSemiMinoraxis) {
    Ellipse2D e = new Ellipse2D.Double(((Background.getWidth()) / 2) - (gblSemiMajaxis / 2), ((Background.getHeight()) / 2) - (gblSemiMinoraxis / 2), gblSemiMajaxis, gblSemiMinoraxis);
    ellipseList.add(e);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setPaint(Color.white);

    for (Ellipse2D e : ellipseList) {
        g2.draw(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: it owuld seem teh only thing stopping the code from working is the bit that creates the ellipse array :9 Thank you Charles for the code :)

Comment: is there a certain package that i need to import for this code to work?

Comment: @Sam Castledine: I added the dependencies for you.

Comment: @Sam Castledine: ArrayList<Type> is Java 1.6+ only - are you using a previous version of Java?

Comment: i thoguht i had the latest version but now i am doubtign myself. the code compiles now but nothing is displayed on the screen am i missing something obvious?

Comment: @Sam Castledine: can you post your full code so I can test it?

Comment: You haven't added an ellipses to the paint list?  There is no use of the createEllipse() function in your code.  I mean... what do you think creates the ellipses? :P

Comment: I added `System.out.println("paint ellipses: "+ellipseList.size());` before the ellipseList loop in paint() and it always said `0`.  You need to rectify that!

Comment: i feel like such an ass now, work wonderfull and now ive put in a function that clears the array as well:) one last thing tho is that the firs ttime the program runs u have to click the button twice before it will draw anything?

Comment: It works fine for me after replacing the `gblSemiMajaxis = semiMajaxis; gblsemiMinoraxis = semiMinoraxis;` with `createEllipse(semiMajaxis, semiMinoraxis);` in the file you gave me.  Only have to press the OK button once but it draws something tiny the first time around if you don't change the planet from Mercury.

Comment: Works beautifully!! thanks charles ive put you in the comments seriosuly cheers man

Comment: @Sam Castledine: please tick the answer then. :P

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving your class a member variable of type `ArrayList<Ellipse2D>`.  When your user enters their input, create the Ellipse2D and add it to the list.  In your paint function, you could iterate over the list and paint each of the Ellipses you've already made.  When the user wants to clear all of the Ellipses, you could use the ArrayList's `clear()` method.

Comment: Kool thanks, however using the code below given by Charles netbeans is having a head fit about the ArrayList<Ellispe2D> bit the rest of it it accpeted by netbeans